# RabbitMQ: Pika: Add timeout while consuming

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

How can I add timeout in RabbitMQ consumer using Pika library so that every new message in the queue waits for a timeperiod to be processed by the consumer?
I am using a Blocking Connection

Answer (score 0):

Use add_timeout callback as mentioned in the [docs](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingConnection.add_timeout)

Comment: yeah i tried adding it but it is not helping, can you post a code as example.

Comment: add_timeout uses a one time timer, not very helpful here.